# Calling one Activity from another

Tags: android

How can I call another activity from one (the current) activity?  I want to call an activity which contains a dialog message box from my current activity.

Comment: What do you mean call the activity? Are they running in parallel or you just wanna create a new activity?

Comment: actually one activity is running and after completing one task on that activity i want to call another activity..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply put your message in bundle and pass it to intent. On Next Activity's onCreate function extract the bundle and show.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("message","your message");
Intent i = new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

In next Activity's onCreate:

```
String message = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("message");
```

show the message now....

Comment: if you want to show the message in next activity, you can simply show in a toast/popup dialoge with ok button... its simple. what do you want?

Answer (score 7):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i=new Intent(yourpresentactivity.this, nextactivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```