# how to link the class shown below with main activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

here is the code of the class which i created which extends MainActivity and how can i call this from MainActivity?
I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong on referencing my surface view class, not my view. I only did the view as an example.  Here is my main class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap; 
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

 public class SurfaceViewExample extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

     OurView v;
     Bitmap ball;
     float x,y;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        v=new OurView(this);
        v.setOnTouchListener(this);
      ball=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.tennis_ball);
        x = y = 0;
        setContentView(v);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        v.resume();
    }
    public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
      Thread t;

      SurfaceHolder holder;

      boolean isItOk=false;

  public OurView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        holder=getHolder();
    }


    public void run() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while( isItOk ==true)
        {
         //drawing   
         if(holder.getSurface().isValid()) {

            continue;

         }

     Canvas c=holder.lockCanvas();
         c.drawARGB(255,150,150,10);    
         c.drawBitmap(ball, x+(ball.getWidth()/4), y+(ball.getHeight()), null);

         holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);     

        }
     }
    public void pause()
    {
        isItOk=false;
        while(true) {
            try {
                t.join();
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            break;

        }
    }

    public void resume()
    {
       isItOk=true;  
       t=new Thread(this);
       t.start();
    }

     }
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
      } 




  }
```

Comment: What happens when you issue an use an `Intent` for it?

Comment: `Intent`s are how you navigate between `Activity`s in android. Read and try to understand http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html. If you get stuck, ask a new question on here with the specific problem you're having!

Comment: here is my main activity which have reference to another class...And my question s how to run this surfaceViewExample...Main Activity is -> 
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    public class Madhu1Activity extends Activity {

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      Drwwingtheball v;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                v = new Drawingtheball(this);
                setContentView(v);
      }
 }

Comment: Here's an example of how to start one Activity from another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity

Answer (score 0):

The much i got is that you want to go SurfaceViewExample  from your main activity for that you need to use intent on button click like

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SurfaceViewExample.class);

startActivity(i) ;
```

and you have to add a permission in menifest to got to that activity like

```
<activity android:enabled="true" android:name="SurfaceViewExample" />




and you can see these links also
```

[Calling one Activity from another in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152564/calling-one-activity-from-another-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html