# Android: Go to another activity onclick button

Tags: android

I add this in my MainActivity.java

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.aboutTheDeveloper);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void openAboutTheDeveloper(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, aboutTheDeveloper.class));
    }
}
```

I have also edited my manifests:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".aboutTheDeveloper"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about_the_developer" >
    </activity>
```

Scenario:

I have this button inside MainActivity.xml with id = @id/openAboutTheDeveloper

Which should open the AboutTheDeveloper Activity.

Inside button I also placed android:onclick="openAboutTheDeveloper"

Which should call function openAboutTheDeveloper inside MainActivity.java

It doesn't seem to work. T_T

Sorry if I'm too explicit. I'm very new to Android and I'm not really friends with Java.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152564/calling-one-activity-from-another-in-android

Comment: What error are you getting? Also please post openAboutTheDeveloper code

Answer (score 5):

you can't have

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void openAboutTheDeveloper(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, aboutTheDeveloper.class));
    }
}
```

The `View.OnClickListener` interface has no `public void openAboutTheDeveloper(View v)` method, but `public void onClick(View v)`. You can either change your onClickListener like

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, aboutTheDeveloper.class));
    }
}
```

removing the `android:onclick` property from your xml, or you get rid of that code, and add a method inside `MainActivity`

```
public void openAboutTheDeveloper(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, aboutTheDeveloper.class));
}
```

the property `android:onclick` let you declare a handler that will be invoked at runtime. The method will be resolved with the reflection and if it is not found, Android throws an exception

Comment: Wow! Thanks @Blackbelt.

I retained the onClick = "openAboutTheDeveloper"

and added the method openAboutTheDeveloper()